# Can anybody explain this unexpected result from boost::thread?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-thread

Consider the following program built against `boost v1.53`. I would expect `z = 10` as output, but the program prints `z = -1294967296`. Can anybody explain why?

```
// g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -lboost_system -lboost_thread main.cpp && ./a.out
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/thread.hpp> // boost v1.53

struct S {
    boost::packaged_task<void> task;
    boost::thread th;
    void async_start(int z) {
        auto worker = [=]() {
            boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds{1});
            std::cout << "z = " << z << '\n' << std::flush; // does not z have the same value as the async_start arg?
        };
        task = boost::packaged_task<void>{worker}; // is not 'worker' copied?
        th = boost::thread{std::move(task)}; // start
    }
};

int main() {
    S s;
    s.async_start(10);
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds{3}); // wait some time to make the thread finish
    s.th.join();
}

// z = -1294967296
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.  It outputs 10 for me and Valgrind does not report any invalid memory access.

Comment: The command to compile does not work for me, `main.cpp` should be supplied before linker arguments. My System prints 10 with boost 1.56 and g++ 4.9. You may want to try and define `BOOST_THREAD_VERSION=x`. Certain code its included or excluded depending on what version you use. The most recent is 4.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on coliru as well, but I can when using boost v1.53.Could  it be a bug in boost v1.53?

Comment: @Martin Can you run the faulty program through Valgrind to see if it reports invalid memory access?  And yes, reverse the linker flags to `-lboost_thread -lboost_system`.

Comment: @5gon12eder No errors from valgrind: ==15373== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Comment: defining #define BOOST_THREAD_VERSION 4 and rewriting the task type to boost::packaged_task<void()> does NOT solve the problem in my boost v1.53.

Comment: This is really strange.  I have no idea what might cause this behavior.  It could indeed be a bug but I find it hard to imagine how that could happen without a memory corruption.  The only other thing to try out would be to see if the effect can be perturbed out by adding parameters, changing types, etc.

Comment: Note that inside async_start() z is really 10. I tried with g++4.8 and g++4.7.2 on x86 and ARM. The problem is always reproducible.

Comment: It could be a missing `-pthread` option. The manual says you need it for proper multithreaded behavior.

Comment: @DanielKO with -pthread the bug is still there.

Comment: There's no reason to have `task` be a member of the `struct`, it's destroyed immediately after it's created.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I know, in the real code task is local indeed , but the problem is still there

Comment: Reproduced with g++4.9.1 + boost 1.53: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9120R3MbclG47klk; does not reproduce with boost 1.54 http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/oZOdRA6gQYHuLCl6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be Boost [bug 8596](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8596), fixed in Boost 1.54.

Briefly, in C++11 mode, `boost::packaged_task`'s constructor is broken when passed an lvalue, storing a reference (!) instead of a copy. The functor is taken by forwarding reference, meaning that the template parameter was deduced to be an lvalue reference when an lvalue is passed. The code apparently neglected to strip the referenceness.

As confirmation, passing a prvalue to `packaged_task`'s constructor (by using the lambda expression directly) [fixes the problem](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/teUEscVvF5dObh0b):

```
    task = boost::packaged_task<void>{[=]() {
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds{1});
        std::cout << "z = " << z << '\n' << std::flush;
    }};
```

and [so does passing an xvalue](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Imc4XuPXm2AS7J9r) by using `std::move(worker)`.